# Delphi, Authentication from database

Tags: delphi

I am planing to include *authentication* capabilities in my program.

I need information about switching between table records. My current program is only reading the **username** and **password** from the first record.

How do I move to subsequent table records?

Comment: That's great to hear! :-) What you're having trouble with ?

Comment: problem is in that how to make programm switch to next record if current records usern. and pasw. checking fails

Comment: You should look up the TDataSet.Locate method. It moves the record to matching criteria, and returns false if the record is not found

Comment: Hmm, i realy dont know what are u talking about. Im comparing authentications forms edit.text fields with DBedit.text fields... If you would say what code rows should be added, that would be great, ty! !!

Comment: If your database supports SQL it could be easier to execute a SQL `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERTABLE WHERE <username>=:param1 and <password>=:param2` statement - instead of navigating through a dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `TDataSet.Locate`. In all of the below, I'm using `ds` to represent your `TDataSet` variable.

```
UserName := EditUserName.Text;
Password := EditPassword.Text;
if ds.Locate(UserName, ['UserNameField']) then
begin
  if ds.FieldByName('Password').AsString = Password then
    // Passwords match
  else
    // Passwords don't match
end
else
  // User name not found
```

To move from one record (row) to the next, simply use `ds.Next;`, and to move to the one before use `ds.Prior;`. To go to the first row, use `ds.First`, and `ds.Last` to go to the last one.

This is really basic database programming. You should probably search for a tutorial that explains it and work through it.

Answer (score 1):

Dataset has a Next method, that way you may traverse the whole dataset.

```
qDS.Open ; 
while not qDS.EOF do
begin
   anyString := qDS.fieldbyname('usern').asString ; // will give you the username
   qDS.Next ; // go to the next record in the dataset.
end ;
qDS.close ;
```